# LINQ to SQL - Stored Procedure Return Type Error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

On SQL 2005 I have a simple SP that selects rows from a table. The SP does not use temporary tables or return multiple result sets. In VS2010 I drag the SP from the Server Explorer to the DBML designer and the SP is added to the LINQ data context. Everything works okay. If I then script the table and SP on to another live SQL 2005 server I am getting the error "The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected .. " Like I say, no temp tables or multiple result sets that would typically produce this error. Could there be something else on the server causing this?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUsers]
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SELECT top 100 * from Users
    END
```

Comment: Same question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927006/linq-to-sql-cant-modify-return-type-of-stored-procedure

Comment: that's the same result not sure if the cause is the same in this instance though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the reason it was failing on the live server is to do with privilages needed to access the meta-data on the DBMS. These are needed to create the return value data type from the SP. By elevating the SQL user account and then dragging the SP on onto the DBML designer .. bingo .. it works!

Comment: Not a particularly helpful resolution - you should include the precise steps you performed so that others can do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

as the first line in your SP after the 'BEGIN' statement.

If your SP does not have this, then it returns messages like

```
'10 Rows affected...'
```

Which Linq tries to interprete as part of the function result.  Iv'e had it bite me loads of times!!

Comment: Without seeing your SP then Alan i couldn't say what else it might be.  @Mark Pim Can I ask what edits you have made to my post please?

Comment: @Mark Pim.. ahh yes, that old chestnut... not one of my strong points :-) (Sorry to put here, couldn't see how to reply privately)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Linq to SQL, and a frustrating one. It also seems to be somewhat unpredictable. The only way I have gotten around this, reliably, is by not having L2S call a stored procedure when I need it to return a result set. I have it call a table-valued UDF instead. L2S seems to have no problems with these, and I've never experienced any problems using them.

Comment: it's certainly unpredictable. i can't see why identical db objects break on the live server. i'll try refresh-rebuild first

Comment: okay, I can't see why the DBML designer couldn't create the return type for identical objects on live box but I cut and paste the XML using the DBML designer which gets round the issue. am looking into ..

Answer (score -1):

Use

create procedure Getxxxxxxx

@xxxxx uniqueidentifier
,@xxxxx uniqueidentifier

set fmtonly off
   //you query
set fmtonly on

Comment: I got this message even with fmtonly off. The problem was I was creating a temp table using the SQL OUTPUT clause which apparently it can't get metadata from. I updated it to OUTPUT into a table variable instead and that solved it.

Comment: Non-sense post - no details, not proper code - totally unhelpful.